# Variable does not exist: portalUserInfo.conAccount.Id in Query

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql, database, unexpectedexception

Please help with this error:

```
String query = 'SELECT Project__c,'
              + ' Project__r.Testing_Submitted__c,'
              + ' Project__r.Project_Sub_Phase__c,'
              + ' Project__r.DRD_Submited__c,'
              + ' Protected_Application__r.DRD_Completed__c,'
              + ' Protected_Application__c,'
              + ' Project__r.Id,'
              + ' Project__r.Name,'
              + ' Project__r.Project_Type__c,'
              + ' Project__r.Remark__c,'
              + ' Project__r.Record_Type_Name__c,'
              + ' Project__r.RecordTypeId,'
              + ' Project__r.Project_Actual_Completion__c,'
              + ' Protected_Application__r.Application__c,'
              + ' Project__r.Project_Phase__c,'
              + ' Project__r.Ready_for_Testing__c,'
              + ' Project__r.recordType.DeveloperName,'
              + ' Project__r.Project_Sub_Status__c,'
              + ' Project__r.Certification_was_submitted__c,'
              + ' Project__r.Customer_confirmed_launch_date__c,'
              + ' Protected_Application__r.Application_Type__c'
              + ' FROM ProjectAppLink__c ';


projectList = Database.query (query + ' WHERE Project__r.Project_Status__c = \'Open\' and Project__r.Account__c = :portalUserInfo.conAccount.Id and Project__r.Online_Project__c = true and Project__r.recordType.DeveloperName in: settingMap.keySet()');
```

**Edit:**
First issue was resolved thanks to @Ratan - changed the Map to a Set.

I got another error '**Variable does not exist: portalUserInfo.conAccount.Id**' but it does exist. When I try to make a regular query it's working just fine.

I then tried to revise the code:

```
        projectList = Database.query (query + ' WHERE Project__r.Project_Status__c = \'Open\' and Project__r.Account__c = :' 
        + portalUserInfo.conAccount.Id + ' and Project__r.Online_Project__c = true and Project__r.recordType.DeveloperName in: settingSet');
```

But now I get: '**Only variable references are allowed in dynamic SOQL/SOSL.**  '

Comment: you can't use map.keyset() in dynamic query.. store in a set variable and use that in dynamic query..

Comment: Very hard to see why you would be getting this variable does not exist error without showing us where you are defining portalUserInfo.

Comment: @TSmith - without the dynamic query it returns records as it should. the variable definitely exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike inline SOQL, [dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) can’t use bind variable fields in the query string. In doing so will result in a **Variable does not exist error**. Exactly what you are seeing.

**Problem:**

```
:portalUserInfo.conAccount.Id
```

**Solution:**

Resolve the variable field into an Id and use the id in your dynamic SOQL query.

```
Id conAccountId = portalUserInfo.conAccount.Id;
projectList = Database.query (query
    + ' WHERE Project__r.Project_Status__c = \'Open\''
    + ' and Project__r.Account__c = :conAccountId' 
    + ' and Project__r.Online_Project__c = true'
    + ' and Project__r.recordType.DeveloperName in: settingSet');
```

Comment: Dynamic SOQL support simple bind variables but not references. Please find this link for ref:https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm